# Is there a way to use a list as a result with Specflow + Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, specflow

I'm new to Specflow and I use the "Specflow + Excel" version.

I would like to test a property inside my model (List).

Is it possible to use a list as a result? What will be the Excel format?

EDIT :

For example, I would like to test the result of a search.

I pass a search criteria as a first parameter. My second parameter is the result of the search.

```
| searchCriteria | result |
```

The result is a list of elements and an element looks like :

```
| id | name | value | date |
```

In fact, I would like to have a nested table.

What will be my Excel format? Is it possible to do it without creating a huge mess?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your scenarios and show us which of the fields should be used from excel?